# How to wipe html special chars like &nbsp; and others from text with the help of PHP?

Tags: php

How to wipe html special chars like `&nbsp;` and others from text with the help of PHP?

Answer (score 9):

.....

```
$newtext = html_entity_decode($your_text);
```

You got to remove `&nbsp;` separately:

```
$newtext = str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $newtext);
```

If you want to remove `html tags` too, you can use:

```
$newtext = strip_tags($newtext);
```

.......

**Relevant Functions Reference:**

**[html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)**

**[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)**

**[str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)**

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try with [`html_entity_decode`](https://www.php.net/html_entity_decode) ;-)

For example :

```
$html = "this is&nbsp;a text";
var_dump($html);
var_dump(html_entity_decode($html, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
```

Will give you :

```
string 'this is&nbsp;a text' (length=19)
string 'this is a text' (length=15)
```

Note that you might need to specify the third parameter -- the charset -- if you are not working with `ISO-8859-1`.