# How can I remove "&nbsp;" from the beginning a string?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to wipe html special chars like &nbsp; and others from text with the help of PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403714/how-to-wipe-html-special-chars-like-nbsp-and-others-from-text-with-the-help-of)

I have this string:

```html
&nbsp;6:30
```

How do I remove `&nbsp;`? Exploding is not working.

Comment: Question title is not appropriate, environment is not given.

Answer (score 4):

should work with

```
trim(html_entity_decode($s))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = "&nbsp;6:30";

$string = str_replace("&nbsp;","",$string);

echo $string;
```

or

```
$string = " 6:30";

$string = trim($string);

echo $string;
```